# ошибка в коде нейросети на 3 нейрона

Tags: c#, матрицы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Изучаю язык, решил написать нейросеть на 3 нейрона. код написан, но где-то ошибка. при компиляции в консоли выдается сообщение об исключении "System.ArgumentException". не знаю как нужно отредактировать код, чтобы он выполнялся. буду благодарен за любую помощь.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra;
using MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Double;

class Program
{

    public double rain = 0.0, wish = 0.0, maths = 0.0;
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello. This is my test programm.");
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the nuber from 0.0 to 1.0 for rain, wish and maths.");
        Console.WriteLine("1.0 - Yes, 0.0 - No");
        Console.ReadKey();
        double rain = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        double wish = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        double maths = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("should you go: " + Predict(rain, wish, maths));
    }

    public static double Activations_fuction(double x)
    {
        if (x >= 0.5)
        return 1;
        else
        return 0;
    }

    public static bool Predict (double rain, double wish, double maths)
    {

        bool res_1 = true;
        Matrix<double> last_ficking_matrix_in_this_code_i_hope = DenseMatrix.OfArray(new double[,]
        {
            {1}
        });
        Matrix<double> input = DenseMatrix.OfArray(new double[,] 
        {
            {rain, wish, maths},
        });

        Matrix<double> weight_input_to_hiden = DenseMatrix.OfArray(new double[,] 
        {
            {0.25, 0.25, 0},
            {0.5, -0.4, 0.9},
        });

        var weight_hiden_to_output = DenseMatrix.OfArray(new double[,] 
        {
            {-1, 1},
        });

        Matrix<double> hiden_input = weight_hiden_to_output * input;
        Console.WriteLine("hiden_input: " + hiden_input);

        Matrix<double> hiden_output = hiden_input.Map(Activations_fuction, Zeros.Include);
        Console.WriteLine("hiden_output: " + hiden_output);

        var output = weight_hiden_to_output * hiden_output;
        Console.WriteLine("output: " + output);

        var output_final = output.Map(Activations_fuction, Zeros.AllowSkip);
        if (output_final == last_ficking_matrix_in_this_code_i_hope)
        {
            res_1 = true;
            return res_1;
        }
        else return res_1 = false;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Вы нам викторину `найди ошибку` предлагаете?

Comment: @tym32167 я только учусь, поэтому не могу найти ошибку самостоятельно и прошу помощи у других. код я предоставил в надежде, что кто-то попробует скомпилировать его, и поймет, в чем заключается ошибка

Comment: Никто не будет гадать что в вашем коде не так. Проведите информацию что ваш код делает, что в нем работает не так, как вы ожидаете, как оно работать должно, как вы сами пытались решить вашу проблему и что не получилось. Без этого никто ваш вопрос даже читать не будет.

Comment: @tym32167 спасибо за совет, отредактировал вопрос

Comment: 1) укажите, что вы вводите с консоли, когда запускаете программу 2) На какой строке конкретно исключение?

Comment: Правило умножения матриц: `(k,m) х (m,n)`.

Comment: @Igor спасибо, подзабылись операции с матрицами

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса